# How to use clip-path polygons in FF and IOS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, clip-path

I try to write a little plugin, to open modal boxes in a more organic fashion, therefore I have decided to animate the clip-path property.

Now this code only works in chrome:
http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/GgGzYo?editors=011

It looks like [firefox does not support](http://caniuse.com/#search=polygon) `polygon()` in the clip-path property. Safari & Mobile Safari do struggle with it as well.

Is there a similarly easy way to make this work in Firefox and Safari and Mobile Safari as well? Any idea how I could approach this problem?

Here is a working example:

```js
var $ov = $('.overlay');

$(document).on('click touchstart', '.inner', function(){
  var coords, coordArray, coordsString;

  coords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

  coordArray = [
    Math.floor(parseInt(coords.left)) + 'px ' + Math.floor(parseInt(coords.top)) + 'px',
    Math.ceil((parseInt(coords.left) + parseInt(coords.width))) + 'px ' + Math.ceil(parseInt(coords.top)) + 'px',
    Math.ceil((parseInt(coords.left) + parseInt(coords.width))) + 'px ' + Math.ceil((parseInt(coords.top) + parseInt(coords.height) )) + 'px',
    Math.ceil(parseInt(coords.left)) + 'px ' + Math.floor((parseInt(coords.top) + parseInt(coords.height) )) + 'px'
  ];


  coordsString = 'polygon(' + coordArray[0] + ',' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';

  $ov.css({
    '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
    'clip-path': coordsString
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    $ov.addClass('show');
  },50);

  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },100);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },180);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },260);

  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0 100%)';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },340);

  // reverse
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1500);

  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1580);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0% 0%,' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1640);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(' + coordArray[0] + ',' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
        'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1740);



   setTimeout(function(){
    $ov.removeClass('show');
  },2000);

});
```

```css
body, html {
  background: silver;
}

.grid {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25vw;
  box-shizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 111ms;
          transition: background-color 111ms;
}
.inner:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

.overlay.show {
  opacity: 1;
  will-change: clip-path;
  -webkit-transition: clip-path 200ms;
          transition: clip-path 200ms;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-clip-path 200ms;
          transition: -webkit-clip-path 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: You could use an SVG for Firefox - http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: @Paulie_D oh! I did not know that you can reference a SVG as clip-path, i will play around with this thank you... Still wonder if there is a cross-browser solution / hack for that do

Comment: Here's a nice little article [**https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/**](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) and this [**Support Chart**](http://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/)

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: @j08691 it only works if you have the CSS, HTML and JS together. Is my question not clear enough? PS: I just added it doe

Comment: Even more reason to post the relevant code in your question. If codepen ever goes away or goes down, then your question loses all value without the code in the question itself.

Comment: Firefox supports clip-path only with the path defined in SVG.

Comment: You don't state what kind of content will be in the boxes (images, text, DOM elements)? if they will follow the shape of the polygon, zoom in, be cropped in original state etc..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to take a look at svgs as you can animate the points of a polygon and morph it to the desired shape.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/VYgoyO)**

**[DEMO With images and titles](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ZYPpdR)**

This demo uses the [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) library to make the squares and manipulate them on the click event.
<s>It is currently **not finished** and there are some bugs but you should get the idea</s>.

I totaly refactored the code, thanks to [rlemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) for helping me get it way better. I tested it in latest FF and Chrome and a user reported it works on an iphone with safari.

The items are made with polygons, a square polygon is added on click and it's points are animated one by one to be featured.

```js
var items = [
  [ 1, 1,24, 1,24,24, 1,24],
  [26, 1,49, 1,49,24,26,24],
  [51, 1,74, 1,74,24,51,24],
  [76, 1,99, 1,99,24,76,24],
  [ 1, 26,24, 26,24,49, 1,49],
  [26, 26,49, 26,49,49,26,49],
  [51, 26,74, 26,74,49,51,49],
  [76, 26,99, 26,99,49,76,49],
  [ 1, 51,24, 51,24,74, 1,74],
  [26, 51,49, 51,49,74,26,74],
  [51, 51,74, 51,74,74,51,74],
  [76, 51,99, 51,99,74,76,74],
  [ 1, 76,24, 76,24,99, 1,99],
  [26, 76,49, 76,49,99,26,99],
  [51, 76,74, 76,74,99,51,99],
  [76, 76,99, 76,99,99,76,99]
],
    item = [],points= [],i, p=[],open = 0,
    s = Snap().attr({viewBox:"0 0 100 100","fill":"#585247"});

function runAnimations(el) {
  if( !animationSequences.length ) return;
  var sequence = animationSequences.shift();
  el.animate(sequence,120,mina.linear, runAnimations.bind(null,el));
}


function register(x,i) {
  item[i] = s.polygon(items[i]);  
  item[i].click(function () {
    var featured = s.polygon(items[i]).attr({"fill":"#585247"});
    p = items[i];
    animationSequences = [
      {"points": p[0]/2+","+p[1]/2+","+p[2]+","+p[3]+","+p[4]+","+p[5]+","+p[6]+","+p[7]},
      {"points": p[0]/3+","+p[1]/3+",100,0,100,100,"+p[6]+","+p[7]},
      {"points": p[0]/4+","+p[1]/4+",100,0,100,100,0,100"},
      {"points": "0,0,100,0,100,100,0,100"},
    ];
    runAnimations(featured);
    featured.animate({"fill":"#ACA696"},300);
    featured.click(function(){
      this.stop().animate({"points":p,"fill":"#585247"},200,mina.linear,featured.remove);
    });
  });
}
items.forEach(register);
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body{background:#E3DFD2;}
svg{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="http://thisisa.simple-url.com/js/snapsvg.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for the effort! I will try this in different browsers.

Answer (score 7):

Clip-path only supports numbers for point values, it looks like you are using percentages/pixel scales which is why it will be failing in firefox.

Change to integer values:

```
coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,123 0,' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
$ov.css({
  '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,
    'clip-path': coordsString
});
```

You will need to remove pixel references from the coordArray and calculate actual int values from the percentages.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem where my clipped element was not showing as clipped on iPhoneX.

Adding webkit solved it for me:

`clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a lot of possibilities, but according to http://caniuse.com/#search=polygon polygon is not support in FF (!). I've tried a lot of possibilities but each time the FF dev tools tell me that it is not a correct value.

My tested code (from your codepen):

```
var $ov = $('.overlay');

$(document).on('click touchstart', '.inner', function(){
  var coords, coordArray, coordsString;
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth + "";
  coords = this.getBoundingClientRect();

  coordArray = [
    Math.floor(parseInt(coords.left)) + ' ' + Math.floor(parseInt(coords.top)) + '',
    Math.ceil((parseInt(coords.left) + parseInt(coords.width))) + ' ' + Math.ceil(parseInt(coords.top)) + '',
    Math.ceil((parseInt(coords.left) + parseInt(coords.width))) + ' ' + Math.ceil((parseInt(coords.top) + parseInt(coords.height) )) + '',
    Math.ceil(parseInt(coords.left)) + ' ' + Math.floor((parseInt(coords.top) + parseInt(coords.height) )) + ''
  ];


  coordsString = 'polygon(' + coordArray[0] + ',' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';

  $ov.css({
    '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

    'clip-path': coordsString
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    $ov.addClass('show');
  },50);

  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },100);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0 ,'+windowWidth+' 0,' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },180);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,'+windowWidth+' 0,'+windowWidth+' '+windowWidth+',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },260);

  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,'+windowWidth+' 0,'+windowWidth+' '+windowWidth+',0 '+windowWidth+')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },340);

  // reverse
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,'+windowWidth+' 0,'+windowWidth+' '+windowWidth+',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1500);

  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,'+windowWidth+' 0,' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1580);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(0 0,' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1640);
  setTimeout(function(){
    coordsString = 'polygon(' + coordArray[0] + ',' + coordArray[1] + ',' + coordArray[2] + ',' + coordArray[3] + ')';
    $ov.css({
      '-webkit-clip-path': coordsString,

      'clip-path': coordsString
    });
  },1740);



   setTimeout(function(){
    $ov.removeClass('show');
  },2000);

});
```